# How to run Android test for all flavors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I need to run Android test for all flavors in Android Studio.

Having a test (**ApplicationTest** instrumentation) and Android Studio allows me to run it for selected flavor.
I have a lot of **flavors** (250) so I need to somehow say it to **run for every flavor** or something like that, and leave it to run one after other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the connectedAndroidTest gradle command - either from the command line or in the right hand side gradle menu - it should be under 'verification' tab.

Comment: That's it/ From Android Studio's terminal I run it as " ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest" and it runs test for all flavors for all started emulators.  I had too many flavors so I having some problem with adb + emulator so I have to stat it as several test with groups of flavors manualy but that is some other story. Thanks a lot for your help!